# SPARQL for getting movies list with proper attributes ordered

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get list of movies in a specific year (just say 1990) with each movie and it's attributes. I tried different ways to get SPARQL but couldn't. How do I group genres into single column?

The format I would want is with some of the properties from here
http://schema.org/Movie

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX q: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?q ?film_title (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?genreID); separator=", ") as ?genre) WHERE {
  ?q wdt:P31 wd:Q11424.
  ?q rdfs:label ?film_title filter (lang(?film_title) = "en").
  ?q wdt:P136 ?genreID.
  ?genreID rdfs:label ?genre.
  ?q wdt:P161 ?actorID.
  ?actorID rdfs:label ?actor filter (lang(?actor) = "en").
} LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of aggregate functions usually need to build the group of things/rows on which you want to apply the function, i.e. a `GROUP_BY` on the projection variables that do not denote the result of an aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT ?q ?film_title (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?genreID); separator=", ") as ?genres) WHERE {
  ?q wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  ?q rdfs:label ?film_title . 
  FILTER (lang(?film_title) = "en")
  ?q wdt:P136 ?genreID .
  ?genreID rdfs:label ?genre .
  ?q wdt:P161 ?actorID .
  ?actorID rdfs:label ?actor 
  FILTER (lang(?actor) = "en")
} 
GROUP BY ?q ?film_title
LIMIT 100
```

#### Some comments:

- it's not clear whether you want to get the genreID or the label of the genre, for the latter indeed you have to use the variable `?genre` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?genre); separator=", ")`
- it's not allowed to re-assign a variable name that has already been used in the query, that's why I changed the name to `?genres`
- don't put a comma after a FILTER, I don't know why you did so
- you don't select the actor, thus, it remains unclear why you use the last triple pattern + FILTER in your query
- your query is quite expensive, thus, its execution might timeout